# Best action hook for placing ical requests

Tags: hooks, urls

I would like to offer an iCal or webCal request on one of my pages. Which hook would be best to intercept the request that comes via URL?

At the moment I use the following hook for this:

```
add_action ( 'init', 'webcal_events');
function webcal_events ()
{
    
    if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] == '/events/webcal')
    {
    header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="events.ics"');
      ... do ICS stuff
    exit(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: You could create a custom rest api endpoint, seems like it would fit really will with your needs

Comment: Isn't the rest api for handling json requests? i need an .ics file at the end